# Solr data-import error log

Tags: solr, lucene, dataimporthandler

I have Solr 3.6 powering search on a Wordpress site I maintain, and this morning I saw that Sorl could not execute a data import. I was attempting to run http://example.com:9393/solr/wordpress/dataimport?command=full-import. Whereas until today the import would chug happily along, now I am getting only the message, `Indexing failed. Rolled back all changes.`

I'm probably missing something obvious, but where does Solr keep the data import logs? I would like to check them out to see what the problem is, but I have not been able to find the right logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solr does not have exclusive log file for data-import, log statements related to data-import process are written to standard log file that Solr writes to. If you are using Tomcat it should be `../logs/catalina.out` .

Error could be caused by any number of problems between Solr, Data source, perhaps the data itself. You might want to check the following questions as well

[Indexing failed. Rolled back all changes. (Solr DataImport)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990015/indexing-failed-rolled-back-all-changes-solr-dataimport)

[solr dataimport error: Indexing failed. Rolled back all changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234598/solr-dataimport-error-indexing-failed-rolled-back-all-changes)

Comment: Thanks! I am using glassfish, and on my setup the log was simply called `server.log`.